# Using Ampscript, RegExMatch and Replace, email address name, for another value, for tracking purpose only

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

For tracking purposes only, I want to replace any characters before the **@** symbol, with a specific ID stored in a DE?
Example:

44helloworldz@gmail.com

to

0031Q001gu**@gmail.com**

I want to keep the domain address as is, just replace anything before the **@** symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the AMPScript function **[Domain()](https://ampscript.guide/domain/)** combined with a **[Concat()](https://ampscript.guide/concat/)** to do this.

Something like:

```html
%%[ SET @id = AttributeValue("myID")
    SET @domain = Domain(emailaddr)
    SET @newEmail = CONCAT(@id,"@",@domain)
]%%
%%=v(@newEmail)=%%
```

Which would output: `0031Q001gu@gmail.com` instead of `44helloworldz@gmail.com`.

@LukasLunow's answer is another great way to do it, but I have found using Domain is a bit more performant and less risk so I wanted to share.

---

Based on your comment, I would look to get the last 9 digits of ID like so:

```html
%%[ SET @id = AttributeValue("myID")
    SET @startIndex = SUBTRACT(Length(@id),8) /* 8 instead of 9 to grab the 9th digit in SubString */
    IF @startIndex > 0 THEN 
      SET @finalID = SubString(@id,@startIndex,9)
    ENDIF
    SET @domain = Domain(emailaddr)
    SET @newEmail = CONCAT(@finalid,"@",@domain)
]%%
%%=v(@newEmail)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you, both very good answers, really appreciate it! In connection with the same functionality I am unable to grab only the last 9 alphanumeric characters from the ID in a string of 20 or more characters that can vary with times.  .Example:[01112W14151617A8SA20] I need only the last 9 characters [617A8SA20]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IndexOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm) and [Substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) functions to locate the @ in the email address string, and use [Concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) to join the ID in front of the domain:

```
%%[
VAR @id, @email, @output, @domain
SET @email = "44helloworldz@gmail.com"
SET @id = "0031Q001gu"
SET @domain = Substring(@email,IndexOf(@email,"@"))
SET output = concat(@id,"**",@domain,"**")
]%%
```